# Moq a data source for a web service

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, web-services

I'm working on a fairly complex multi-tiered application and I'd like to mock the data source for one of the layers as it's very difficult for it to get to the database much of the time. (Some of it doesn't even exist yet.)

What I'd like to be able to do is set a flag in one of the web services to have it use the mocked data source instead of the database connection. I'm just going to put data in xml files. I've successfully used moq in unit tests but it seems I can't make that mental leap to where I can replace the injected database with the mock at run time.

**The Stack:**

- VS 2013
- .Net 4.5.1
- Ninject
- Entity Framework 5?
- SQL Server 2012
- Several attached databases that are called via stored procedures in SQL Server
- Moq 2.x
- WCF
- Web API 2

Comment: Create a mock implementation for your interface and register it with ninject. Inside the mock implementation read your XML file.

Comment: Eugene S.: That's a nice and concise way to describe what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than set a flag, why not use and interface and pass that in? E.g. `IDataSource`.

Your web service, for example, takes an `IDataSource` as part of its construction.

Then, your moq can implement the interface and you can pass that in, rather than a *real* implementation of `IDataSource`. Similarly, your real database would implement the interface, too...

```
public class MoqDataSource : IDataSource
{
    ...
}

public class RealDatabase : IDataSource
{
    ...
}
```

As for replacing the real data source, at run time, you could use some kind of factory class that returns an `IDataSource`, and then use any number of methods to decide what the factory returns.

E.g. the factory reads some config file, and depending on what you've set there, it either returns a real data source, or the moq...

```
public class DataSourceFactory
{
    public static IDataSource CreateDataSource()
    {
        if (/* are we using real data source */)
        {
            return new RealDatabase();
        }
        else
        {
            return new MoqDataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter whether you call it a *factory* or something else... it's just one way of encapsulating the creation of an `IDataSource`. Only the factory class needs to be concerned with what type of `IDataSource` you want to create, the rest of the application doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the easiest way might be to use a file that you can set the dependency information into. This way, you can switch between the Moq and the actual data source with a simple xml file change (could even drive that using different build targets, etc. but that's going beyond the scope of your original question).

In order to integrate an xml file for Ninject to consume, you will need an extension:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml

HTH...